# NameError: name 'self' is not defined Explain

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to understand how "self" works. In this first code I got error but I belive I did everything right. After that I try few more things to figure it but could not. What am I missing here?

```
class myClass:
    def foo(self):
            print('WORKED')
    self.foo()
```

> NameError: name 'self' is not defined

---

```
class myClass:
    def foo(self):
            print('WORKED')
    foo()
```

> TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

---

```
   class myClass:
       def foo():
               print('WORKED')
       foo()
   myClass.foo()
```

> WORKED
>   WORKED

(in here pylint give warning that says "Method has no arguments")

---

Comment: `self` is the instance on which you call the method like `o = myClass(); o.foo()` you may learn on Oriented Object code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct usage is:

```
class MyClass:
    def foo(self):
        print('WORKED')

    def bar(self):
        self.foo()


obj = MyClass()
obj.bar()
```

You have to define the method with the parameter `self`. It will be automatically passed as `obj` when calling `obj.foo()`. That is, `obj.foo()` is equivalent to `MyClass.foo(obj)`.

Comment: so I can not call a methot inside a class within self? ( calling `self.foo()` in MyClass )

Comment: @hhilal you can use `self` inside a method, from that perspective it's just another function argument. See the edited version where bar calls foo.

Answer (score 0):

Why?

```
class myClass:
    def foo(s):
        print('WORKED', s)
        return s
    s = foo(1)
    print("Hello")
myClass.foo(2) 
print(myClass.s)
```

[Result](https://ideone.com/AxUoiX):

```
WORKED 1
Hello
WORKED 2
1
```

So if you call `foo()` without `self` it will be considered as a class field. If you ommited field declaration (i.e. `s = foo(1)` being `foo(1)` directly) it will execute also (as your code) but will not store result anywhere.

You cannot `s = self.foo(1)`, because `self` will not be defined outside a member function. However, you can call it directly `s = foo(1)` and store in member `s`

Answer (score 0):

Others have provided examples of code which runs, but I think there's a deeper issue of not understanding how *Python* works.

The thing to understand here is that unlike other languages like Java or C#, in Python the "body" of a class *is a block of code* which gets executed during the creation of the class.

`class` creates a special scope, then all the inside the body is run, then the class is created using all the symbols collected in the class body. It's also different from Ruby where first the class is created then the body is executed (and it has a `self` representing the class itself and you can call methods like `attr_accessor`): in Python first the body is executed *then* the class is created.

An other thing to note is that in Python `self` is not exactly magical, rather when you write `obj.foo()` Python executes it as `type(obj).foo(obj)`. Technically you don't even have to call the first parameter `self`.

This means:

- in your first snippet, right after your defined the method you tried to call it on something which doesn't even exist a this point (you've not created a `self` you could call)
- in your second snippet, the function exists in the scope but it's not been converted to a method yet, so it's still waiting for one positional parameter.
- in your third snippet, the function exists in the scope and takes no parameters and you can call it, *however* if you try to call it on an instance afterwards it's not going to work properly

PS: essentially you can think of:

```py
class Foo:
    ...
```

as a shorthand for

```py
def Foo_body:
    ...
    return locals()
Foo = type("Foo", (object,), Foo_body())
```